# How to remove noexec from /dev permanently (Ubuntu 20.04.2)

Tags: kernel, mount, udev

An executable binary is executing mmap() with PROT_EXEC on /dev/zero causing EPERM (Operation not permitted) on our Ubuntu 20.04.2 server (fully up to date). It is not possible to replace the binary nor will the vendor provide an update in the near future.

I found out that /dev/zero has noexec due to:
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=32889584k,nr_inodes=8222396,mode=755)

I've been able to confirm resolution of the problem by executing:
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev

What are possible solutions to fix this problem permanently? Basically, I would only need exec on /dev/zero as a workaround for the executable binary. If this is not possible I would assume there must be a way to drop the noexec on /dev even after rebooting the system.

Thanks

Comment: I would think what you need is MAP_ANONYMOUS https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html and thus do not need to change something crucial as /dev/ (?)

Comment: I do not have the source code so I cannot change the implementation. That's why I mentioned 'binary executable'

Comment: The real question is, "Why does that binary want to execute `/dev/zero`?"

Comment: It's probably a bug but I need to work around it for as long as it has not been resolved.